# For every 100 in int add 1

Tags: objective-c, int

This is super simple maths but I can't get it working. I am trying to add 1 to my int for every 100 stored in a dynamic int.

For example if `myInt = 350` then `intNumber = 3`.
**or**
`myInt = 570` then `intNumber = 5`

To clarify I don't want a remainder hence why I don't want `x/100`

I know its similar to but obvious not:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Why not `myInt / 100`?

Comment: because I dont want a remander

Comment: @user3629527 At the moment, 4 people has told you the same thing. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial:

```
int myInt = 350;
int intNumber = myInt / 100; // will be 3
```

Comment: but then its 3.5 not 3

Comment: @user3629527 No it's not.

Comment: No it's not. It's 3. Learn about integer division in C-based languages.